# PagedDataSource Count

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using `pageddatasource` to make paging for `datalist` control, but when binding `pageddatasource` to linq query, the count doesn't change although the result of query is different (`ResultQuery_Count = 13` AND `PagedDataSource` count always 10). and `IsFirstPage` and `IsLastPage` always true as well

here's the Code :

```
PagedDataSource objPage = new PagedDataSource();
try
{
    objPage.AllowCustomPaging = true;
    objPage.AllowPaging = true;
    objPage.DataSource = Getter.GET_GeneralResult();
    objPage.PageSize = 8;
    objPage.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;
    lbtnNext.Enabled = !objPage.IsLastPage;
    lbtnPrev.Enabled = !objPage.IsFirstPage;   
    DataList1.DataSource = objPage;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the query is updated, did you rebind the datalist?

Comment: did ypou mean bind datalist with pageddatasource ? yes i bind it but the problem is i got the first 10 records only not all records :S

Comment: Put a break point on DataList1.DataSource = objPage and see if the number of records is correct when your query changes.  This way you will know if it's an issue with the data or an issue with the binding.